# Two different normal distributions - probability A > B

Tags: probability

If I take a single sample A from a normal distribution with mean M1 and variance V1 then take a sample B from a normal distribution with mean M2 and variance V2, then what is the probability that A>B ?

I dare say this question has been asked and answered many times, but I don't know what combination of words to search for.

For the record, this is not homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $P(A>B)=P(A-B>0)$. If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $A-B$ is a normal random variable with the mean $M_1-M_2$ and the variance $V_1+V_2$. So you need to calculate the probability that a normally distributed random variable with the mean $M_1-M_2$ and the variance $V_1+V_2$ is positive.