# N different normal distributions - probability A is largest

Tags: probability

Following on from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707245/two-different-normal-distributions-probability-a-b) question, I now have a harder version I need to solve. If we have N numbers selected from N normal distributions, each with its own mean and variance, what is the probability that a particular number is the largest. So for example we choose $A,B,C$ and $D$ from distributions with means $M_a,M_b,M_c,$ and $M_d$ and variances $V_a,V_b,V_c$ and $V_d$, then what is the probability that:

$$A > \max\{B,C,D\}$$

Comment: How are they JOINTLY distributed? $\qquad$

Comment: I'm guessing you are asking if they are correlated with each other in any way and the answer is no. They are independent of each other.

Comment: This is simple for $N=2$, as $A-B$ has a normal distribution but for larger $N$ I would be inclined to go for numerical or Monte Carlo integration

Comment: I can do monte carlo, but speed may be an issue. I would prefer a numerical method - presumably that'll be numerically integrating some function - but I don't know what that function would be.

Comment: I updated my answer, you should check it out and let me know if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: @animal_magic: thank you for your effort. As a non-mathematician it will take me some time to fully understand. Though I see it has been upvoted already by someone that undoubtedly knows better than me. I'm struggling to work out the exact meaning of the capital F. Once I can recognise the answer as being in the form of an integral of a function, I am comfortable with the rest. But my confusion about the F means I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: $F_{X_i}$ is the cumulative distribution function for the random variable $X_i$, which is a normal random variable with a given mean and standard variation. You can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

Edit: $F_{X_i}(x)$ is just integral of the normal distribution corresponding to $X_i$, and the integral is taken from $-\infty$ to x. We don't have a closed form solution for it's integral, but it can be evaluated numerically. In other words, $F_{X_i}(x) = P(X_i \le x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Ian for pointing out my mistake (independence issues). I've got ANOTHER answer and some code for you. I tested it out properly with R via Monte Carlo simulation. I'll provide the R code and the Mathematica code. I used Mathematica to numerically evaluate the integral I derive below.

So let's say we have $N$ distributions, and each $X_i$ is distributed according to the $i^{th}$ distribution. Let's assume without loss of generality that we are interested in $P(X_1 \ge \max_i X_i)$. I'm going to be a little loose with the notation, but I think it'll be clear.

$$\begin{align}
P(X_1 \ge \max_i X_i) &= P(X_1 \ge X_2, X_1 \ge X_3, \ldots, X_1 \ge X_N)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X_1 \ge X_2, X_1 \ge X_3, \ldots, X_1 \ge X_N, X_1 = x) dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X_1 \ge X_2, X_1 \ge X_3, \ldots, X_1 \ge X_N| X_1 = x) f_{X_1}(x) dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X_1 \ge X_2, X_1 \ge X_3, \ldots, X_1 \ge X_N| X_1 = x) f_{X_1}(x) dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X_1 \ge X_2|X_1)P(X_1 \ge X_3|X_1)\ldots P(X_1 \ge X_N| X_1 = x) f_{X_1}(x) dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(x) \prod_{i=2}^N F_{X_i}(x) dx\\
\end{align}$$
where $f$ denotes the PDF and $F$ is the CDF. At this point, it's reasonable to evaluate the integral numerically.

Here is some Mathematica code to show an example of how to evaluate the above expression. Say

- $X_1$ ~ N(1,2)
- $X_2$ ~ N(0,1)
- $X_3$ ~ N(2,1)
- $X_4$ ~ N(1.5,3)

Then to get $P(X_1 \ge \max_i X_i)$ we just run the following in Mathematica

```
NIntegrate[
 CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]*CDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1], x]*
  CDF[NormalDistribution[1.5, 3], x]*
  PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 2], x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

We can get answer of 0.216147.

Now let's check our answer with R. Here's code for running a Monte Carlo simulation. Note that it took me around 2 minutes to run.

```
x1 = rnorm(10^8, 1, 2)
x2 = rnorm(10^8, 0, 1)
x3 = rnorm(10^8, 2, 1)
x4 = rnorm(10^8, 1.5, 3)
indicators = ifelse(x1 >= pmax(x2, x3, x4), 1, 0)
mean(indicators)
```

I just ran it and I got 0.2161365, which is pretty close to what we expect. I tried different numbers of variables and different distributions, and it always worked. Hopefully I understood your problem correctly and this helps you.

Comment: The independence doesn't seem to make sense here: knowing $X_1 \geq X_2$ makes it more likely that $X_1 \geq X_3$. This was the point made by Qaswed.

Comment: Thanks @Ian I updated my answer. I think it's in good shape now.

Comment: Looks correct now. Intuitively you condition on $X_1=x$, then the event is $X_2 \leq x,\dots,X_N \leq x$, where $x$ is now *fixed*, so you can properly use independence. Then you marginalize over $x$. That's a nice approach. It is also fairly conducive to numerical integration, given a fast routine for computing the normal CDF.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with numerical integration, that's straightforward enough. The joint pdf is

$$f(x_1,\dots,x_N)=\prod_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma_i}} e^{-\frac{(x_i-\mu_i)^2}{2\sigma_i^2}}.$$

Now supposing you want $X_1$ to be the biggest, then you just integrate over the region $x_1>x_2,x_1>x_3,\dots,x_1>x_N$. This is

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dots \int_{\max \{ x_2,\dots,x_N \}}^\infty f(x_1,\dots,x_N) dx_1 dx_2 \dots dx_N.$$

However, I will warn that if $N$ is even slightly large (say, 10), this integral will probably be faster to compute by Monte Carlo integration than by direct integration. This is a manifestation of the "curse of dimensionality". If you really want to use direct integration, one approach would be Gauss-Hermite quadrature: given the $m$ nodes $x_j$ and $m$ weights $w_j$ for one dimensional Gauss-Hermite quadrature (meaning that $\sum_{j=1}^m w_j f(y_j) \approx \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} f(x) e^{-x^2/2} dx$), your integral can be approximated as

$$\sum_{i_1=1}^m w_{i_1} \sum_{i_2=1}^m w_{i_2} \dots \sum_{i_N=1}^m w_{i_N} f(\mu_1+\sigma_1 x_{i_1},\mu_2+\sigma_2 x_{i_2},\dots,\mu_N+\sigma_N x_{i_N})$$

where $f(x_1,\dots,x_N)=1$ if $x_1=\max x_i$ and $0$ otherwise. Since this function is discontinuous, the convergence rate will probably be just decent, not great. Moreover, as you can see you will need $m^N$ evaluations to use this rule at all, which is large when $N$ is large even if $m$ is just $2$.

Answer (score 0):

To ask for $p_{A} = P(A > max(B,~C,~D))$ is equivalent to ask for $P(A > B~ \land ~A > C~ \land ~A > D)$.

---

Edit: I think my initial answer was wrong, so I reworked on it, without being able to show a final solution yet.

$P(A > B~ \land ~A > C~ \land ~A > D) = P(A > B) \cdot P( A > C~ \land ~A > D|A > B) = P(A > B) \cdot P(A > C|A > B) \cdot P(A > D|A > B, A>C)$.

Comment: Not really an answer :-(

Answer (score -1):

Let us say the $A$ we are looking for is $A_k$ and we want to see if it is largest in the set $\{A_1,\cdots,A_n\}$. My initial thought is to fix $A_k$ and then calculate the probability that none of the other $A_i$ is pairwise larger and then use complementary probability:

$$P\left(\max_i A_i\leq A_k| A_k\right) =1-\prod_{\forall i \neq k} P\left(A_i\leq A_k\right)$$

Then what would be needed is to sum or integrate over all $A_k$:

$$P\left(\max_i A_i \leq A_k\right) = \sum_{\forall A_k} P\left(\max_i A_i \leq A_k|A_k\right)\cdot P(A_k)$$

If you have a table for normal distribution function, this becomes easy, just the product of a series of table lookups ( maybe you want interpolation in between table entries ). You will need to calculate which entry of the table to check for each $A_i$ but it will be a a really nice function of its mean and variance. This will be nice to express with vectors too, in case you want to try it in a computational language like R or Matlab or Python or Octave.

Comment: $$\bigcap_{i \neq k} \{A_i\leq A_k\}=\left\{ \max_{i \neq k}A_i\leq A_k\right\}$$$$\prod_{i \neq k} P(A_i\leq A_k)\ne P\left( \max_{i \neq k}A_i\leq A_k\right)$$

Comment: Iff all other are smaller, then the maximum of them is not larger and then *complementary probability* therefore the 1 minus before.

Comment: Yeah this refers to the identity between events that I recalled in my comment, which is true. But the identity between probabilities is not, except if $A_k$ is almost surely constant.

Comment: Oh wait, I am calculating the probability given that we know $A_k$, am I not.

Comment: Is this more reasonable?

Comment: With $A_k$ drawn from a normal distribution? No it is not (reasonable).