# Probability of one RV of normal distribution being maximum among other two RV of different normal distributions

Tags: probability

I have a following example question I created. Let $ X \sim N (2, 4^{2}) $ and $ Y \sim N (3, 3^{2}) $ and $ Z \sim N (5, 7^{2}) $. If we sample each once, $ x $ and $ y $ and $ z $, what is the probability that one is the maximum over others?

I read the link ([N different normal distributions - probability A is largest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850961/n-different-normal-distributions-probability-a-is-largest)), but I still have difficulty computing it. I ran Monte-Carlo simulation,

```
import numpy as np

p_max = [0, 0, 0, ]
for i in range(100000):
    np.random.seed(i)
    p1 = np.random.normal(2, 4)
    p2 = np.random.normal(3, 3)
    p3 = np.random.normal(5, 7)
    if p1 == max(p1, p2, p3):
        p_max[0] += 1
    elif p2 == max(p1, p2, p3):
        p_max[1] += 1
    elif p3 == max(p1, p2, p3):
        p_max[2] += 1
  
print(sum(p_max))
print(p_max[0] / sum(p_max))
print(p_max[1] / sum(p_max))
print(p_max[2] / sum(p_max))
```

I got the answer as 0.21033, 0.26598, 0.52369, respectively. I appreciate if you could provide me a full solution to this question.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**It is straightforward with two variables.**

Assume $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_x,\sigma_x)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_y,\sigma_y)$. Let $f_X$ and $f_Y$ be the density functions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

\begin{align}
P(x>y) &= P(y)P(x>y|y)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Y\mathrm{d}y\int_{y}^{\infty}f_X\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma_y\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-{\frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2}[1+\erf{\left(\frac{y-\mu_x}{\sigma_x\sqrt{2}}\right)]}\right)\mathrm{d}y
\end{align}

For three or more variables, we introduce another random variable, $\mathcal{I}=\max(x,y)$ with a probability density function $f_\mathcal{I}$.

\begin{align}
f_\mathcal{I} &=P(x=i,y<i)+P(x<i,y=i)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma_x\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-{\frac{(i-\mu_x)^2}{2\sigma_x^2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\erf\left(\frac{i-\mu_y}{\sigma_y\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{\sigma_y\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-{\frac{(i-\mu_y)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\erf\left(\frac{i-\mu_x}{\sigma_x\sqrt{2}}\right)\right).
\end{align}

Now, we can use $f_\mathcal{I}$ defined above and calculate
$$
P(x>\max(y,z))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_\mathcal{I}\mathrm{d}\mathcal{i}\int_{i}^{\infty}f_X\mathrm{d}x
$$

If number of variables is more than three, $f_\mathcal{I}$ needs to be adjusted, but the same approach holds.

**Appendix:**

This code snippet verifies $f_\mathcal{I}$

```
q_array=[]
for i in range(1000000):
    q_array.append(max(np.random.normal(1, 4),np.random.normal(6, 3)))
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(q_array, 50, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)
bin_interval=bins[1]-bins[0] #necessary scale to adjust f_I to bins
q=np.linspace(-20,20,500000)
p_array=[]
mx=1 #\mu_x
sx=4 #\sigma_x
my=6
sy=3
P2=lambda i, mx,sx, my,sy:1/(sx*(2*np.pi)**0.5)*np.exp(-(i-mx)**2/(2*sx**2))*(0.5+0.5*scipy.special.erf((i-my)/(sy*2**0.5)))+1/(sy*(2*np.pi)**0.5)*np.exp(-(x-my)**2/(2*sy**2))*(0.5+0.5*scipy.special.erf((x-mx)/(sx*2**0.5)))
for i in q:
    p_array.append(P2(i,mx,sx, my,sy)*100000*bin_interval)
plt.plot(q,p_array)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
for i in range(100000):
    p1 = np.random.normal(1, 4)
    p2 = np.random.normal(6, 3)
    p3 = np.random.normal(9, 7)
    if p1 == max(p1, p2, p3):
        p_max[0] += 1
    elif p2 == max(p1, p2, p3):
        p_max[1] += 1
    elif p3 == max(p1, p2, p3):
        p_max[2] += 1
print(sum(p_max))
print(p_max[0] / sum(p_max))
print(p_max[1] / sum(p_max))
print(p_max[2] / sum(p_max))

P2=lambda i, mx,sx, my,sy:1/(sx*(2*np.pi)**0.5)*np.exp(-(i-mx)**2/(2*sx**2))*(0.5+0.5*scipy.special.erf(i-my)/(sy*2**0.5)))+1/(sy*(2*np.pi)**0.5)*np.exp(-(x-my)**2/(2*sy**2))*(0.5+0.5*scipy.special.erf((x-mx)/(sx*2**0.5)))
P3=lambda z,sz,mz,mx,sx, my,sy: P2(z,mx,sx, my,sy)*(0.5-0.5*scipy.special.erf((z-mz)/(sz*2**0.5)))

mx=1
sx=4
my=6
sy=3
sz=7
mz=9

q=np.linspace(-100,100,500000)
interval=q[1]-q[0]
int_sum=0
for i in q:
    int_sum+=P3(i,sz,mz,mx,sx, my,sy)*interval
print(int_sum)
```

For $X\sim\mathcal{N}(1,4^2)$, $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(6,3^2)$ and $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(9,7^2)$,  simulation gives `0.053656`, `0.311313` and `0.635031` respectively. The analytic solution is `0.05377948691698057`, `0.3118958251127827` and `0.634324687964007` respectively. Close enough.